# Move character between accounts

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm planning to buy Diablo III for myself. 
However, I'd like to create a second character for a friend of mine, who is not yet convinced. So I want to let them play that character (in my account) for some time, and if they like it, they could get their own Battle.net account and we could play together.

My question: is it possible to transfer that initial character from my account to their new account, or do they have to start over?

Comment: Keep in mind, that while Blizzard usually doesn't bothers to check or enforce it, it is against their ToS to let someone else use your account.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Good call, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Tell him he can keep all his items and give him some money. Some people claim they have reached level 60 within 8 hours with good equipment.

Answer (score 11):

No way to move characters across accounts (or across servers, for that matter) that I know of. So, yeah, start over.

If you have a guest pass to give, I'd suggest you give him that instead.

Comment: Yup.  Starter edition is the way to go.

Comment: Note that you currently have to buy a *boxed copy* to get guest passes.

Comment: There are some places where you can buy/ get guest passes online. example: http://www.g2play.net/store/Diablo-3-Starter-Edition-Guest-Pass.html

Comment: keep in mind: guess passes don't allow to play together (only if both got guess passes)

Answer (score 3):

For now, guest passes are the best way to do this.

But in the future, Blizzard plans to allow you to **sell characters** across accounts:

> We are also planning to allow players to buy and sell characters in the auction house at some point in the future and will have more details to share on that at a later date.

This is confirmed by the official Auction House FAQ and by Bashiok. See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66767/3241) for more details.

This may or may not be a good way to give a character to a certain person. Perhaps Blizzard will add a "private auction" to allow this. It never hurts to suggest it to them, either.