# Can I move characters to a new account?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move character between accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74329/move-character-between-accounts)

My husband and I bought one copy of Diablo 3 and, after creating some characters of my own on his account and playing around with them for a while, I discovered that I really enjoy the game. Now I'd like to download a second copy of Diablo 3 and create my own account, but I've grown quite attached to my characters and would love to be able to move them to my new account.

Is this in any way possible? How would I contact the admins to request something like this?

Comment: Nice question!!

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple answer: **no**, you can't.